# How to add nested object instead of replacing an existing one in ElasticSearch with PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a "list" of users with an "addresses" property. A user can have multiple addresses. I used the nested type for addresses. Inside my addresses, I have a "rooms" property for which I also used the nested type.
In my frontend, I have a form allowing users to add new rooms. When doing so, the can add a room to an existing address or create a new one.

When I create a new address, the existing address is replaced by the new one. I need the new address to be added so that I have an array of addresses. If I use an existing address, I need the new room to be added to that address.

**My index**

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'users',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 3,
            'number_of_replicas' => 2
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            'properties' => [
                'firstname' => [
                    'type' => 'text'
                ],
                'surname' => [
                    'type' => 'text'
                ],
                'email' => [
                    'type' => 'text'
                ],
                "addresses" => [
                    'type' => 'nested',
                   'properties' => [
                       "id" => [
                           'type' => 'integer'
                       ],
                       "address" => [
                           'type' => 'text'
                       ],
                       "zipcode" => [
                           'type' => 'text'
                       ],
                       "city" => [
                           'type' => 'text'
                       ],
                       "country" => [
                           'type' => 'text'
                       ],
                       "rooms" => [
                           'type' => 'nested',
                           'properties' => [
                               "id" => [
                                   'type' => 'integer'
                               ],
                               "name" => [
                                   'type' => 'text'
                               ],
                           ]
                       ]
                   ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

**The update function**

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'users',
    'id'    => $user_id,
    'body' => [
        'doc' => [
            'addresses' => [
                "id" => $address->id,
                "address" => $address->address,
                "zipcode" => $address->zipcode,
                "city" => $address->locality,
                "country" => $address->country,
                "rooms" => [
                    "id" => $room->id,
                    "name" => $room->room_name,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$client->update($params);
```

How can I add a new address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using a painless script as suggested by [llermaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3112848/llermaly). I had to adapt some things and I added a condition to be able to add rooms to an existing address.

Note: In the form I use to add new rooms, the user can select an existing address on create a new one. I have to check if the address is a new one or not and adapt my code...

```
if($request->existing_id === 0) {  // if 0 -> the address is a new one
  $params = [
   'index' => 'users',
    'id'    => $user_id,
    'body' => [
        'script' => [
        'lang' => "painless",
        'inline' => "if (!(ctx._source.addresses instanceof Collection)) {ctx._source.addresses = new ArrayList(); ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)} else {ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)}",
        'params' => [
            'data' => [
                "id" => $address->id,
                "address" => $address->address,
                "zipcode" => $address->zipcode,
                "city" => $address->locality,
                "country" => $address->country,
                "rooms" => [
                    "id" => $room->id,
                    "name" => $room->room_name,
            ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
} else {
  // first I need to know the index of the selected address
  $params = [
    'index' => 'users',
    'id'    => $request->user
  ];
  $response = $client->get($params);
  $addresses = $response["_source"]["addresses"];
  $targetAddress = array_search($address->id, array_column($addresses, 'id'));
 
  // Then, I can add a room to it
  $params = [
    'index' => 'users',
    'id'    => $request->user,
    'body' => [
      'script' => [
        'lang' => "painless",
        "source" => "if (!(ctx._source.addresses[".$targetAddress."].rooms instanceof Collection)) {ctx._source.addresses[".$targetAddress."].rooms = new ArrayList(); ctx._source.addresses[".$targetAddress."].rooms.add(params.data)} else {ctx._source.addresses[".$targetAddress."].rooms.add(params.data)}",
        'params' => [
          'data' => [
            "id" => $room->id,
            "name" => $room->room_name,

          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
  $client->update($params);
}

$result = $client->update($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `add` method in a painless script :

```
$params = [
 'index' => 'users',
  'id'    => $user_id,
  'body' => [
        'script' => [
        'lang' => "painless",
        'inline' => "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)",
        'params' => [
            'data' => [
                "id" => $address->id,
                "address" => $address->address,
                "zipcode" => $address->zipcode,
                "city" => $address->locality,
                "country" => $address->country,
                "rooms" => [
                    "id" => $room->id,
                    "name" => $room->room_name,
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
];

$result = $client->update($params);
```

As a side note :

**Object field type let to do searches like:**

*"Property A and/or B on any of the addresses"*

**Nested field type searches like:**

*"Property A and/or B on the same address"*

Not all nested fields needs to be of nested type. Only if you need to keep the relation between properties of the same children to do queries.

Comment: I have an error "failed to execute"  `"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"dynamic method [java.util.LinkedHashMap, add/1] not found"`

Comment: Seems like fails with the users with no addresses. You can try with this alternative:

            'source' => 'if (!ctx._source.containsKey("addresses")) ctx._source.addresses= new ArrayList(); ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data);',

Let me know if worked to update the answer.

Comment: I add to do this : `"source" => "if (!(ctx._source.addresses instanceof Collection)) {ctx._source.addresses = new ArrayList(); ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)} else {ctx._source.addresses.add(params.data)}",`

Comment: My issue now is that I cannot add a room to an existing address. I try the same code to add a room but it does not work. When I create a new address with a room, the room is not an instance of Collection. When I add a room to an existing address, the existing room is replaced...

Comment: You have another function to add rooms to an address? can you share it?

Comment: @Thbwun I'm glad you made it!

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer really helped me to resolve my problem !